# How Can I Fix This LNK1104 Error in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, emulation, libmysql

First off, allow me to give you some background. I'm attempting to emulate a game from my childhood. A lot of work has been done with respect to [emulating said game](https://github.com/VanaDev/Vana), and I've made some decent progress through the windows setup guide that can be found [here.](https://github.com/VanaDev/Vana/wiki/Windows-setup-guide)
I recommend taking a look at that first, because knowing the prior steps I've done will probably help in answering this.

Currently I'm on step 10, building the Vana solution. When I build it in Visual Studio 2019, I encounter 3 errors. The login, channel, and world server projects cannot open “libmysql.lib”. The output is as follows:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libmysql.lib'`

And under the error list it reads:

`LNK1104    cannot open file 'libmysql.lib'`

It’s not telling me why it cannot open it, it just says that it can’t open it. It’s not giving me any location, or much clues as to what exactly I should do. I found “libmysql.lib” within the MySQL server community 8 folder and I put the file within the SQL folder in the “LazurBeemz” directory, but got the same error.

I then tried putting it into the MySQL server 5.0 folder because that’s where I pointed the “LazurBeemz” pack to, unfortunately I got the same exact errors. Honestly I have no idea where exactly I should put it or why I’m getting these errors. It’s beyond me. I checked the specifics of the error code (LNK1104), and it has a PLETHORA of possibilities. The main thing I need to know is WHERE should this file go?

Any Thoughts?

[Here is a picture of the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDgMb.png)

Comment: The error is most likely one or more of  the following 3 things: 1.  The library is not in any of the folders listed in your linker->general->additional library directories setting for your project, 2. You are mixing 32 and 64 bit, or 3. The library file is corrupt.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for the help! So I've traveled to the  linker->general->additional library directories setting. It has it as this: $(MySqlDirectory32)\lib;$(Configuration)_VC$(PlatformToolsetVersion)\Common;$(LazurBeemz)\$(PlatformToolsetVersion)\lib\$(Configuration);%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories) How do I find this? I can't seem to find this location on my computer. I've never seen a directory with dollar signs ($) and such. I've searched both of my drives and it came up empty handed.

Comment: That means you have not added the location of `libmysql.lib` to this list. You need to do that.

Comment: ***I've never seen a directory with dollar signs ($) and such*** Those  are variables that are available in visual studio that help you with projects. Your library will not be in any of these locations and you should not try to put it there. These locations are for the system files.

Comment: @HarryFlores `$(MySqlDirectory32)\lib` This sounds like where where `libmysql.lib` is supposed to be, but you probably don't have the `MySqlDirectory32` build variable configured. Easiest way to set it up would be to define an environment variable `MySqlDirectory32` pointing to the actual directory where you have it. Or, simply replace `$(MySqlDirectory32)\lib` with the actual directory, though you will have to do that in all places where the project references it.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to find out the file directory where the `libmysql.lib` is located.

Then, you could select `Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories-><Edit...>` and add `libmysql.lib` file storage directory.

[image]

Finally, you could select `Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies` and add the name of `libmysql.lib`.

[image]

Note: You need to perform similar operations on `debug` version and `release` version.